# Java - Playing audio from a read InputStream online

Tags: java, audio, text-to-speech

I've been struggling with this for a while now and I decided it was time I needed to ask for help.

So basically IVONA is a TTS(text-to-speech) service that has a way of using it in Java with a key(which I have).

Though, there is a sample class that they give you, [Link to Sample Class](https://github.com/IvonaSoftware/ivona-speechcloud-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/IvonaSpeechCloudCreateSpeech/SampleIvonaSpeechCloudCreateSpeech.java) . Which shows you how to use the API and save it as an MP3.

**I'm asking how would I modify this class to rather than saving the MP3 it reads, how can I make it so it plays it via Clips and AudioSystem's.**

I appreciate all and any responses, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        InputStream is = null;//Actual InputStream here

        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is));
        clip.start();
```